# 5v to 3.3v and 1.8v power regulator incorrect voltage output

Tags: power

I have designed 5v to 3.3v and 1.8v power regulator using PAM2306AYPKE and implemented on a PCB. I've prototyped 3 boards and on all 3 of them the voltage on the 3.3V rail is 2.6v-2.8v. The regulator produces 1.8v on output 2 as expected. Since it's the same problem on 3 PCBs I've ruled out that this could be caused by a soldering issue. [image: schematic]

[image: Layout]

Comment: Voltage under load?

Comment: Both Voltage with no load and voltage while running the compute module is around 2.6-2.8V

Comment: While it might not be the reason, your ground and hot switching loops are far from ideal

Comment: Your PCB layout it really bad. Why didn't you follow the manufacturer's recommended (and therefore tested and thoroughly validated) layout as shown in their datasheet?

Comment: @sstobbe Could you elaborate please? Do you mean the ground plane in side the 5v loop on the top?

Comment: I was working with space constraints and hence it was hard to follow the suggested layout

Comment: Did you hand solder the QFN? There may be a cold joint somewhere

Comment: QFN and all SMD parts were soldered using a hotplate and bridges were removed using a soldering iron.

Comment: Look at where the bypass cap is for vin1... is that the 3v3 rail

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but your PCB layout (and schematic for that matter) is a mess, especially as you have 4-layers. Switching regulators are very sensitive to PCB layout. You've used very thin traces to connect everything which will not work well. There are very large distances in the ground between chip and capacitors. The inductors are a long way from the chip through very very thin traces. Your bypass caps are all in weird orientations. And the ground plane is massively broken up. The main power input feed runs under the inductor (avoid anything running under the inductors!)

Comment: Looking at manufacturer's layout, the bottom slug is the main power path for switchers. Your ground wire is skinny and convoluted.. I doubt that you can make a layout smaller than the suggested and have any good result. I am afraid your placement won't fly. Start over.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys I'll start over with a new layout

Comment: To conclude with some guess. Under no load this regulator falls into "pulse skipping mode", meaning that it makes short pulses once in a while. With poor layout there likely is some excessive and unexpected ringing, so the feedback circuit gets confused, resulting somehow in lower output. The switchers need careful layout.